# merge 3 data.frames by column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have three independent `data.frames`. The three `data.frames` have the same number of columns and the same number of rows. Additionally They have the same column names. I' m trying to merge the three data.frames according to column names. I'm using the following code wrote to merge two data.frames and return the number of matches.

> ```
> Merged_DF = sapply(names(DF1),function(n) nrow(merge(DF1, DF2, by=n)))
> ```

The problem is that while in this example there are two data.frames, in my case I have 3 data.frames. 
How can I modify the code to merge three data.frames instead of two? I tried to modify the string in this way simply adding the third data.frame but it does not work:

```
  Merged_DF = sapply(names(DF1),function(n) nrow(merge(DF1, DF2, DF3,  by=n)))
```

It returns the following error:

```
 Error in fix.by(by.x, x) :  'by' must specify column(s) as numbers, names or logical
```

Ex:

> DF1
>
> ```
>  G1  G2  G3
>   a   b   f
>   b   c   a
>   c   d   b
> ```
>
> DF2
>
> ```
>  G1  G2  G3
>   A   b   f
>   b   c   a
>   h   M   b
> ```
>
> DF3
>
> ```
>  G1  G2  G3
>   a   b   f
>   b   l   a
>   j   M   v
> ```

The data.frames have around 250  rows and 50 cols.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After researching this very same question for a couple hours today, I came up with this simple but elegant solution using a combination of 'dplyr' pipes and the base R 'merge()' function.

```
MergedDF <- merge(DF1, DF2) %>%
              merge(DF3)
```

As you mention in your post, this assumes that the column names are the same and that there's the same number of rows in each data frame you are merging.  This will also automatically eliminate any duplicate columns (i.e., identifiers) that were used in the merging process.

Comment: As of R 4.1.0 you can now use the native pipe `|>` so you do not need to import the magrittr pipe (if you are not working in the tidyverse).

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `Reduce` function to merge multiple data frames:

```
df_list <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3)
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), df_list, accumulate=FALSE)
```

Or `merge_recurse` from the `reshape` package:

```
library(reshape)
data <- merge_recurse(df_list)
```

See also the R Wiki: [Merge data frames](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3adata-frames%3amerge)

Comment: Hi, rcs, thanks a lot! Is it possible to have the count of matches between all the data.frames? Finally I would like to know how many items column by column, the three data.frames shere.

Comment: merge_recourse is no longer in the new reshape2 package and this function has a bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121654/r-why-is-merge-recurse-failing. So the first option is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone wants to merge multiple data frames with the same column name but unequal row numbers, this article was helpful: https://medium.com/coinmonks/merging-multiple-dataframes-in-r-72629c4632a3

Basically, you use the do.call and rbind functions:

```
Merged <- do.call("rbind", list(df1, df2, df3, df4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `tidyverse` packages:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

reduce(list(DF1, DF2, DF3), full_join)
```

By default this will merge by all common columns. For more control you can specify an anonymous formula function where `.x` represents the accumulated value and `.y` represents the "next" value. The comparable expression to the above would be:

```r
reduce(list(DF1, DF2, DF3), ~ full_join(.x, .y, by = c("G1", "G2", "G3")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use bind_rows from dplyr

```
library(dplyr)


bind_rows(df1, df2  ,df3 )
```

caveats and options are here in the documentation

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html

happy merging  :)

Comment: This! The best and fast way in my opinion