# How to merge data based on column of specific data in r

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, multiple-columns, stat

I have three data, every data contain one column and the same rows but in diffrent orders in all the five data, i want to merge the five data based on the first column.

```
      column1
X       7
B        5
Y        2
D        1
Z        0


        column2
D          7 
Z          5
X          2
Y          6
B          7

       column3
Y          4
D          4
Z          8 
B          7
X          2
```

The result i want is like this

```
        column1     column2      column3
X           7          2            2
B           5          7            7
Y           2          6            4
D           1          7            4
Z           0          5            8
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge 3 data.frames by column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291613/merge-3-data-frames-by-column-names) - of not, please edit your question to include why the solutions provided in the link dont work

Comment: No id doesn't work, it gives 64000000  of rows !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

list(df1, df2, df3)%>%
   map(rownames_to_column) %>%
   reduce(full_join, 'rowname') %>%
   column_to_rownames()

  column1 column2 column3
A       7       2       2
B       5       7       7
C       2       6       4
D       1       7       4
E       0       5       8
```

Comment: what us column_to_rownames ??

Comment: @Reda its a function just like anyother fuction. Run the code and see what you get

Comment: Because i had this error message : Error in column_to_rownames(.) : 
  could not find function "column_to_rownames"

Comment: @Reda that is a function in the `tibble` package. Should be loaded automatically by `tidyverse`. Does your code run without the last `%>%columns_to_rownames()`?

Comment: No i got this error too : Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  erreur d'ï¿½valuation de l'argument 'x' lors de la sï¿½lection d'une mï¿½thode pour la fonction 'reduce' : unused argument (rownames_to_column)

Comment: @Reda meaning you do not have the `tidyverse` package? Try loading the following packages `library(purrr);library(dplyr);library(tibble)`

Comment: It seems to work ! thank you so much for your answer !

Comment: @Reda close the question by "marking" one of the solutions provided. You "mark" by clicking the tick next to the solution. Also consider upvoting all the solutions given

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with the `merge` function.

```
df1 <- data.frame(rows = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), column1 = c(7, 5, 2, 1, 0))
df2 <- data.frame(rows = c("D", "E", "A", "C", "B"), column2 = c(7, 5, 2, 6, 7))
df3 <- data.frame(rows = c("C", "D", "E", "B", "A"), column3 = c(4, 4, 8, 7, 2))
result <- merge(df1, df2, by = "rows", all = TRUE)
result <- merge(result, df3, by = "rows", all = TRUE)
print(result)
```

This should give what you want.

```
rows column1 column2 column3
1    A       7       2       2
2    B       5       7       7
3    C       2       6       4
4    D       1       7       4
5    E       0       5       8
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, the issue is that i don't have "rows" in the rownames, i edited my question..

Comment: @Reda So your dataframes only contain 1 column and the ABCDEs are just row indexes? If so I suggest writing the dataframes with `row.names=T` parameter, reading them into R again, and my answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use the following approach:

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

Reduce(merge, lapply(df_list, \(x) 
  cbind(x, xx = row.names(x)))) |> _[-1]

#   column1 column2 column3
# 1       7       2       2
# 2       5       7       7
# 3       2       6       4
# 4       1       7       4
# 5       0       5       8
```

An alternative approach is to reorder by row names then put them all together. It's easier to do this when combining them in a list, then using `do.call` to combine everything back together. I also wrapped it in `setNames` to rename the columns to the desired column names:

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

setNames(do.call(data.frame, lapply(df_list, \(x) x[order(rownames(x)),])), 
         paste0("column", 1:3))

#   column1 column2 column3
# 1       7       2       2
# 2       5       7       7
# 3       2       6       4
# 4       1       7       4
# 5       0       5       8
```

The above is identical to doing it manually, which is slower but may be easier to interpret what's going on:

```
df1 <- df1[order(rownames(df1)),]
df2 <- df2[order(rownames(df2)),]
df3 <- df3[order(rownames(df3)),]

data.frame(column1 = df1, column2 = df2, column3 = df3)

#   column1 column2 column3
# 1       7       2       2
# 2       5       7       7
# 3       2       6       4
# 4       1       7       4
# 5       0       5       8
```

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "column1
A        7
B        5
C        2
D        1
E        0", h = TRUE)


df2 <- read.table(text = "column2
D          7 
E          5
A          2
C          6
B          7", h = TRUE)

df3 <- read.table(text = "column3
C          4
D          4
E          8 
B          7
A          2", h = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but the order doesn't work cuz in fact i want to keep the same order that i have in my first data which i don't get using your answer (the rownames are codes like this XFR44 YZZ888...)

Comment: Thanks Reda, since this works no the sample data, you may want to edit the sample data in your question to better reflect your circumstances.

Comment: @Reda does my edit help? See the (new) first approach

Comment: there's something wrong with the syntax in the first solution : Error: unexpected input in:
"Reduce(merge, lapply(df_list, \(x) 
                     cbind(x, xx = row.names(x)))) |> _"

Comment: @Reda This may have to do with your data - this works on the sample  data. It looks like you may be better off if you edit your question to include `dput(df1)`, `dput(df2)`, etc so we have the exact structure of your data.